# Why not reverting back to DC current as main electricity?

Tags: dc

In the early days the DC current was dominate, until Tesla came with AC because it can by step up/down by using transformer.

But today with advancing in power semiconductor devices, DC can be easily step up/down, most devices at homes are DC powered(or can be DC), in addition high voltage DC is more efficiency in transmission line(compared with AC) and also is less difficult to synchronize with other DC lines.

So why isn't there a comeback of DC as the main electricity?

Comment: Cost, reliability and installed assets. Please capitalise and punctuate properly. Your post gives a poor impression.

Comment: Sorry, i need advance course in English

Comment: Because you'd have to replace every power supply on every device.

Comment: Because the reasons AC was chosen over DC in the past are still valid today even with the DCDC converters we have now. Also AC transformers are much more reliable than any DCDC converter. Also a DCDC converter cannot provide mains isolation, a transformer can.